# System Web HttpException

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4, user-interface

i downloaded a bootstrap and i want to use it in my asp.net MVC project, i added the css files to content folder and the js files to scripts folder , then the code in the index file from this download to my layout , after running the program , i am getting this error: System.Web.HttpException: The following sections have been defined but have not been rendered for the layout page "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml": "featured".
can you please help me, thanks!

Comment: where do you try to change something? I only see GETs

Comment: in new Genre { Name = "Rock" }, i want to change Rock to games , but it's not changing

Comment: you create a new instance of the Genre class, but you don't change an existing object.

Comment: i want to change this existing object, i can't?

Comment: @Fabiano , i am a beginner in MVC , so i need details please about how to change the genre name to a name i want, thanks!

Comment: You have no code that updates anything. I think you would be best continuing to the next step in the [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-5)

Comment: i want to stop here , because i have a little project on making online shop , so i only want categories and products, so i want to change genres rock to games and others , that's all i want, if you ca help me please @Fabiano , thanks!

Comment: it's unclear what you want. It appears to me that you should do some tutorials first as @Scrobi suggested

Comment: what is unclear?, i just want to change genres name , for example Rock to games , when i edit this new Genre { Name = "Rock" }, to new Genre { Name = "Games" }, and run program , on the web it never changes, so i am asking how to change it? @Fabiano

Comment: It is unclear because   1, There is no code above where you do `new Genre {Name = "Games"}`   2, We don't understand if you just want to change the the list of Genres so Rock is Games, or if you want an action on the website that changes the Rock Genre to Games and then updates your database, or something else.

Comment: in the sampledata class , there is new Genre { Name = "Rock" },i want to make it games , not an action on the web, i want to see on the web in store , games instead of rock , thanks! and sorry for asking so many questions , but i am a beginner in mvc and want some help @Fabiano

Comment: Change `DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges` to  `DropCreateDatabaseAlways`. Note that you will lose all changes made  to the data in your database

Comment: i got this : An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Core.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Sequence contains no matching element , @Fabiano

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are not seeing the change in the database are because the below code will only run when the Model (`Genre` or `Albums`) is changed e.g. you added a new field, not when you amend the data.

```
public class SampleData : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<MusicStoreEntities>
    {
        protected override void Seed(MusicStoreEntities context)
        {
            var genres = new List<Genre>
            {
                new Genre { Name = "Rock" },
                new Genre { Name = "Jazz" },
                new Genre { Name = "Metal" },
                new Genre { Name = "Alternative" },
                new Genre { Name = "Disco" },
                new Genre { Name = "Blues" },
                new Genre { Name = "Latin" },
                new Genre { Name = "Reggae" },
                new Genre { Name = "Pop" },
                new Genre { Name = "Classical" },
            };
```

There are other Database Initialisation strategies, `CreateDatabaseIfNotExists`, `DropCreateDatabaseAlways`, you can find more details on these [here](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/database-initialization-strategy-in-code-first.aspx)

To resolve your issue you can either change the Database Initialisation strategy as @Fabiano has suggested to `DropCreateDatabaseAlways`. Be warned this will drop and create the database everytime you run your application.

Or if you have access to your database and have the relevant permissions you can edit the Genre table and then amend the Seed code so that if will be correct if you change your model.

Or you can continue with the tutorials [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-5) and this will show you how to edit, create and delete Genres.

Comment: Ty very much @Scrobi , i think this is all what i need to know, and if i have more questions later about this , i will ask here , Thanks!!